# i am making an application in which i want to select the minimum count of delivery guy which has been allocated to the book for deliver

Tags: sql

i am making an application in which i want to select the minimum count of delivery guy which has been allocated to the book for deliver along with the id

**tables name:**

1. delivery_guy (**column name**: *delivery_guy_id* )
2. book_transation (**column name**: *delivery_guy_id* )

I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT dg.delivery_guy_id,
       (SELECT Count(bt.delivery_guy_id) AS dd
        FROM   book_transaction bt
        GROUP  BY bt.delivery_guy_id
        ORDER  BY dd DESC
        LIMIT  1) AS mincount
FROM   delivery_guy dg;
```

but this not that i want and when i wrote ASC instead of DESC so it returing me **0**

Comment: You want to find out a `delivery-guy` who has minimum deliveries to make?

Comment: You have 2 tables and each table only has 1 column, named delivery_guy_id?

Comment: The subquery has no relation to the base table `delivery_guy`. Please see [mre] and post a) the actual table structure and sample data and b) expected results

Comment: Also, please update the question tags with your DBMS